# print the output of strace command in a text file

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace

I need to write the result of below command to a text file but this command doesn't work and when using `cat output.txt` show me nothing.
could please help me to correct the problem?

> `strace -r -y -e read Program -l -o output.txt`

thanks

Comment: What did you try? What did you find so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I could not find anything more about activity of /mnt. I tried using strace -r -f -y -e trace=write ls/dev/sdb but that is not true command.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, I think the person should have ran it like this:

```
strace -o outputfile.txt ./Program
```

Comment: filed an issue for man strace here: https://github.com/strace/strace/issues/284